# Reading of input of text file into arrays

Tags: java

I have a input txt file which is of format

```
T1, 4, 8
T2, 1, 40
T3, 2, 9
T4, 3, 15
```

How to store the values of that text file that are split by commas in an array?

In commented code, the error I get is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FCFS {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String process_name[], tmp[];
        int tat[], wt[];
        int priority[];
        int burst_time[];
        int i = 0, avg_tat = 0, avg_wt = 0;
        String line = null;

        try {
            Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the file name ");
            String fileName = Keyboard.nextLine()
            FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(file);
            while ((line = myReader.readLine()) != null) {

                // process_name[i] = line.split(",")[0];
                //priority  [i] = line.split(",")[1];

                //burst_time  [i] = line.split(",")[2];
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: If you uncomment the code, what's the exact problem you're having?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

Comment: Splitting a string returns a String array. Your arrays are defined as int arrays. What's unclear about the error?

Comment: How to split int arrays ? or is there any other way to take user input from text file using both string and int array. I am new to java

Comment: You never have an int array. Your file only has strings... Splitting a line only has strings... Do you want to _parse a String_ into an integer? Or do you want change the types of `int priority[];` for example, to a String array?

Comment: I want to parse a String into an integer.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java

Comment: expected (possible future) error: no array is initialized -> NullPointer